# Use another table for users to login in cakephp 3

Tags: php, postgresql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Since I use Cakephp, I used Mysql with Cakephp conventions (Users table with username and password fields).

For some reason, I have to use Postgres database with `loginutil` instead of username and `mdputil` instead of password. And I use a table named `Utilisateur`.

Here is the code I put in AppController.php for Auth component :

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => [
                    'username' => 'loginutil',
                    'password' => 'mdputil'
                ],
                'userModel' => 'Utilisateur'
            ]
        ],
        'loginAction' => [
            'controller' => 'Utilisateur',
            'action' => 'login'
        ]
    ]);
```

In login.ctp I have two input :

```
$this->Form->input('loginutil');
$this->Form->input('mdputil');
```

The login method in my UtilisateurController.php is the default one with `$user = $this->Auth->identify();`

But when I try to login me, `$user` is false. The user is not found.

I tried to put this :

```
$this->Auth->config('authenticate', [
AuthComponent::ALL => ['userModel' => 'Utilisateur'],
'Basic',
'Form'
]);
```

But that's not better.

Did I make a mistake somewhere in my code, or maybe I didn't correctly read the doc ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What does the definition of your `Utilisateur` class look like?

Comment: @GregSchmidt If you mean the `Utilisateur` controller class, I have a beforeFilter in UtilisateurController with `$this->Auth->allow(['index', 'login', 'view']);`. The rest is in AppController.

Comment: Is your database table named "Utilisateur"? It's supposed to be "utilisateurs".

Comment: @ObjectManipulator Yes I know, but for school reasons the table is named "utilisateur" ... I would prefer "users" but for now I can't

Comment: Have you done any of the basic checks that are suggested in other questions about login problems that can be found here on SO? Checked the column type/length, ensured that the passwords are really stored hashed, debugged the queries that are being issued (Do they find anything at all? If there's actually something being found, what exactly is it, does it match the value in the DB?), ensured that hashes are generally being stored correctly when creating a new user, etc...

Comment: @ndm Thanks a lot, the problem was that my password were not hashed.

Answer (score 0):

If your database table is named utilisateur, please specify this line in the Model/Table/UtilisateursTable .php

```
   namespace App\Model\Table;

   use Cake\ORM\Table;

   class UtilisateurTable extends Table {

      public function initialize(array $config) {

          $this->table('utilisateur'); // this line is important, otherwise, it assumes that your database table is utilisateurs
       }

    }
```

Comment: The model was generated with cake bake command, so this line is already present in `UtilisateurTable.php`

Answer (score 0):

Try to Use `public $useTable = 'Utilisateur';` in the model